# How to find out the conditional expectance

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-expectation, binomial-distribution, geometric-distribution

Let $X$ be a random variable with $X\sim\mathrm{Geom}(1/3)$. Let $Y$ be another random variable
with $Y\sim\mathrm{Bin}(n, 1/4)$ where $n$ is the value taken by the random variable X.

I'm trying to find $ E(Y|X=n)$. I know the formula and how to do it if I were given a set of values but how do you tackle the unknown variable?

Comment: Do you mean $P(Y=1|X=n)$ or $E(Y|X=n)$? What if n=0 or n=3, etc… what would $E(Y)$ be?

Comment: Yes E(Y|X=n) sorry. Oh, the Expectation of Y is the same, 1/4p for every n so E(Y|X=n) = n*1/4n?

Comment: Close. What is E(binom(n, 1/4)) for some given value of n?

Comment: @AaronGoldsmith (n choose r)*1/4^r*3/4^n-r. Why do we have to find this when E(Y) is just np?

Comment: That’s the pmf.

Comment: @AaronGoldsmith I don't follow, what is E(bin(n,1/4))?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you said it earlier. If you have n draws with 1/4 chance success, you expect n/4 successes total. The geometric part does not come into play because we essentially come in after finding out $X=n$ for some value $n$ we don’t specify yet.

Comment: So the expectation is just n/4? If so that's really confusing because the formula says to add ALL the values over what y can take given X=n no?

Comment: You can look up a proof that the expectation of a binomial (n, p) is np and that will sum over possible values 0 to n

Comment: As in y=0 to y=n

Comment: To be honest I can actually do the proof for E(Y) = np but I guess I didn't recognise it in the form of this question. That's what I usually fear in probability, not recognising what I need to use despite me knowing the content.

Comment: It sounds like it will come to you as you grow familiar with, e.g. conditional expectation